# Jetty JNDI with Oracle error: IllegalStateException: Nothing to bind for name jdbc/replaydev

Tags: java, rest, jetty, jax-rs, jndi

I have written a JAX-RS REST-API, that fetches rows from Oracle.
For this I have used `JNDI` since I am using `Jetty`. But on deploying the WAR file I am getting the following error:

```
Caused by:
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Nothing to bind for name jdbc/replaydev
        at org.eclipse.jetty.plus.webapp.PlusDescriptorProcessor.bindEntry(PlusDescriptorProcessor.java:914)
```

My web.xml has the following entry:

```
<resource-ref>
 <res-ref-name>jdbc/replaydev</res-ref-name>
 <res-type>javax.sql.DataSource</res-type>
 <res-auth>Container</res-auth>
</resource-ref>
```

WEB-INF/jetty-env.xml has following entries:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE Configure PUBLIC "-//Mort Bay Consulting//DTD Configure//EN"    "http://www.eclipse.org/jetty/configure_9_0.dtd">

<Configure id='wac' class="org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext">
  <New id="replaydev" class="org.eclipse.jetty.plus.jndi.Resource">
    <Arg><Ref refid='wac'/></Arg>
    <Arg>jdbc/replaydev</Arg>
    <Arg>
      <New class="oracle.jdbc.pool.OracleDataSource">
        <Set name="URL">jdbc:oracle:thin://@MY.ORACLE.SERVER:1555/JOBCTL</Set>
        <Set name="User">XYZ</Set>
        <Set name="Password">rockOn</Set>
        <Set name="connectionCachingEnabled">true</Set>
      </New>
    </Arg>
  </New> 
</Configure>
```

And my Java code has the following:

```
Context initContext = new InitialContext();
ds = (DataSource)initContext.lookup("java:/comp/env/jdbc/replaydev");

con = ds.getConnection();
Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver");
```

POM.xml has following dependencies added:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty</groupId>
    <artifactId>jetty-server</artifactId>
    <version>9.2.11.v20150529</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty</groupId>
    <artifactId>jetty-webapp</artifactId>
    <version>9.2.11.v20150529</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty</groupId>
    <artifactId>jetty-plus</artifactId>
    <version>9.2.11.v20150529</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty</groupId>
    <artifactId>jetty-jndi</artifactId>
    <version>9.2.11.v20150529</version>
</dependency>
```

I even tried adding `id` tags in web.xml entry like: `<resource-ref id="replaydev">....</resource-ref>` for jetty-env.xml `<New id="replaydev" class="org.eclipse.jetty.plus.jndi.Resource">`. Its not working either.

Am I missing something??

Comment: [Jetty 9.2 is EOL (End of Life)](https://dev.eclipse.org/mhonarc/lists/jetty-dev/msg02726.html), consider upgrading.

Comment: Could you try without the extra `/` (after the `java:` portion) - aka: `ds = (DataSource)initContext.lookup("java:comp/env/jdbc/replaydev");`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks @voodoo14 and @joakim.
I found the soultion. I actually removed the dependencies shown above in the POM.xml
This is because I already had a standalone jetty v9 running. And I believe that the dependencies mentioned above are creating one more jetty within.
So I removed the dependencies and things worked.

Answer (score 0):

The configuration looks fine. I guess you are using maven. Make sure you are deploying the version of jetty.xml with those modifications. e.g: `mvn clean install`